Bias variance equation in machine learning context
I am reading about the Bias-Variance relation in Statistics. Now I get that the relation is $$MSE(\hat{T},T)=\mathbb{V}ar(\hat{T})+(Bias(\hat{T}))^2$$ where $\hat{T}$ is the estimator of $T$. Lets suppose I am estimating the true function $f$ in Linear Regression, then the relation with the assumption that errors are i.i.d $N(0,\sigma^2)$, we get
$$MSE(\hat{f},f)=\mathbb{V}ar(\hat{f})+(Bias(\hat{f}))^2+\sigma^2 $$ replacing with definitions we get
$$MSE(\hat{f},f)=\mathbb{E}[\hat{f}-\mathbb{E}(\hat{f})]^2 +[\mathbb{E}(\hat{f})-f]^2+\sigma^2 $$. Now my question is how does this equation is equals to $$
 \frac{\sigma^2}{\kappa}+ \left[f(x) - \frac{1}{\kappa}\sum_{i=0}^nf(x_n)\right]^2+\sigma^2
$$. I know from Statistics that $\mathbb{V}ar(\bar{X})=\sigma^2/n$ and I know that $\hat{\alpha}, \hat{\beta}$  are MLE, UNBIASED, CONSISTENT estimators of true parameters $\alpha, \beta$.  Can somebody explain

What is $\kappa$? And you mention $\alpha, beta$ at the end but what is their role in the above equations?
